# Updating Samsung note 2 to android 4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My galaxy note 2 works on version 4.3, Some time ago it started pinging me continuously about upgrading to 4.4. I wasn't ready to do the upgrade then, so I managed to stop getting the notification every three hours.

I would like now to do the upgrade, but when I click on `updates` as explained here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00050889/56008/SPH-L900ZWASPR nothing happens.

How can I upgrade my galaxy note 2 to the latest Android version available for the device?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No worries, If you have not upgraded it till now then the possibility of no OTA update might have occured which does not mean that you cannot update.

Here is it what you need to do:

- Install Samsung Kies
- Connect your Samsung galaxy note 2 to laptop
- Install required drivers for your phone
- Open Samsung Kies and you can find the firmware update for Android 4.4.2

or else here is link to various official release of Android 4.4.2 for note 2

http://androidromupdate.com/2014/08/03/install-n7100xxufne1-galaxy-note-ii-n7100-official-4-4-2-kitkat-update-firmware/

Comment: Kies only installed the new firmware, but Android is still 4.3, and the update button still does nothing.

Comment: The easiest method would be to take it to any Samsung store and get it updated or use the link above.